# How to translate text with price in it - Magento

Tags: magento, translate, magento-1.9

I want to translate the following which appears on my frontend:

excl. 4,95€ Shipping costs.

It's combined with a link and I tried the following which doenst work

`"excl. <a href=""%s""><u>"4,95€ Shipping costs"</u></a>","zzgl. <a href=""%s""><u>"4,95€ Versand"</u></a>"`

Comment: should be like this "first language <a href='#'></a>","other language <a href='#'></a>"

Comment: yes but since there is a 4,95€ in it, it doesnt grab it correctly

Comment: How did you tried in phtml file?

Comment: "excl. <a href=""%s""><u>"4,95€ Shipping costs"</u></a>","zzgl. <a href=""%s""><u>"4,95€ Versand"</u></a>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `Firegento_MageSetup`? Then the string is `"Excl. %s Tax, excl. <a href=""%s"">Shipping Cost</a>"` (you forgot to replace the price with the placeholder `%s`)

Otherwise, find out how exactly it is translated in the template: search for `__('excl. <a href=` in your code base and you should find out.

Comment: I added a custom text next to the price and tried to tranlate it via translate.csv in my custom theme folder. I tried to replace the price with `%s` but it didnt work. Maybe there is a problem since the price is seperated with a comma?

Comment: No. The price is not even in the CSV anymore after you replaced it with `%s`. Did you find the template where the translation happens?

Comment: Since I am pretty new to magento, I'm not quite sure where to search for it. I jused used the translate.csv

Comment: Just search in the whole "app" directory, for example using `grep` or your IDE

Comment: do you mean the file where the text is implemented in? i know that and i know its put in there. but the translation doesnt grab it correctly

Comment: So, it actually was `"excl. <a href=""%s""><u>"4,95€ Shipping costs"</u></a>"` there? Then the € sign might be your problem. Check if the character encodings of the template and the translate.csv match. Both should be UTF-8

Comment: i checked the encodings (both UTF-8) and even when I remove the € sign and just put `4,95` it doesnt grab it.
This is how it's in the template phmtl file:
`__('excl. <a href="%s"><u>4,95 Shipping costs</u></a>'`
And this is the translate.csv:
`"excl. <a href=""%s""><u>%s Shipping costs</u></a>","zzgl. <a href=""%s""><u>%s Versand</u></a>"`

Comment: With this template, the translate.csv should be `"excl. <a href=""%s""><u>4,95 Shipping costs</u></a>","zzgl. <a href=""%s""><u>4,95 Versand</u></a>"`. Do not forget to flush the cache after updating the file.

Comment: Do you know how to add the € sign in some way?

Comment: Just put it there and make sure, the files are utf-8. Alternatively use HTML encoding (`&euro;`)